# Easy Stereo Out for MB SLK230

Tags: audio, mercedes-benz, slk230

I have a 1998 Mercedes Benz SLK 230, I had the battery changed not too long ago and now my stereo system is asking for a code. Mercedes gave me the factory code however that code does not work. Mercedes informed me that I need to remove the stereo to retrieve the serial number off of it in order to find the correct code number. I am completely not one bit at all mechanically inclined. I was hoping someone would be able to tell me how I might take my stereo out by myself without disabling and ruining my whole vehicle. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: [Does this video help?](https://youtu.be/zCEHjFjqQx8)

Comment: If reduced to words, that'd be an answer, @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2. Great video!

Comment: Thanks @DavidSupportsMonica - I knew if Jupiter had put into words what they found, it'd do the job. Leaving it at that.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick search on the web and found this article.  It appears to be applicable to your vehicle. It appears to need some inexpensive special tools. They are flat blades that insert into two slots located at the bottom of the radio. One slot on each side. Sliding the blades in these slots releases the locking tabs that retain the radio. The radio slides out to expose the numbers you need. Push the radio back in until it snaps to reinstall. Again, I've never done one of these so I'm only trusting a website for accuracy. If you see these slots on the bottom of your radio, it should work. The special tools should be available from the dealer, parts store or online. If you know exactly what they look like you could probably improvise.

https://www.pelicanparts.com/techarticles/Mercedes-SLK230/50-ELEC-Radio_Removal/50-ELEC-Radio_Removal.htm